# Jquery reshape div or images

Tags: jquery-plugins

is it possible to make images in a div take the form of a shape or the form inside another image?
Thanks

Comment: Generally, not without `<canvas>`.

Answer (score 0):

well only solution i can think of here is to get width and height of image, and then asign those values to the div u want to resize:

```
var imgWidth = $('#imageid').width();
var imgHeight = $('#imageid').height();
$('#divId').css("height", imgHeight ); 
$('#divId').css("width", imgWidth);
```